# Django 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am new to django and I want to make a like button on posts but I have this error. Thank you!

> 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'

This is my Post model:

```
    class Post(models.Model):
            created_date = models.DateTimeField()
            title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
            profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='poze', blank=True, null=True)
            text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Nimic', blank=True)
            user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            likes=models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name='likes',blank=True )
```

This is my html template:

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load rest_framework %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
 <form method="post"  class="form-signin">
  <div class="card text-center " style="width: 30rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src='' alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
 <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h5>
         <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ post.created_date}}</h6>
         <p class="card-text">{{post.text}}</p>

        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <a href="{% url 'comments' pk=post.id %}" class="card-link">Comments</a>

            <!--<a href="{% url 'like_post' %}" class="card-link" value="{{ post.id }}" name="post_id">Like</a>-->
        </div>


</div>
  </div>
 </form>

<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id}}">Like</button>      //HERE IS THE LIKE BUTTON
</form>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

URL:

```
  url(r'^like/', login_required(views.LikePost), name='like_post'),
```

VIEW:

```
def LikePost(request):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.Post.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

Console:

> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>   August 12, 2018 - 16:28:05
>   Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'DjangoApp.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>   Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
>   Internal Server Error: /account/like/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Robbi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "C:\Users\Robbi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "C:\Users\Robbi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Robbi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
>       return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Robbi\PycharmProjects\DjangoApp\account\views.py", line 198, in LikePost
>       post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.Post.get('post_id'))
>   AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'
>   [12/Aug/2018 16:46:10] "POST /account/like/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72571

Comment: can you add full traceback of the error?

Comment: Sure.I edit my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Django HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) documentation, we could see there is no attribute **`Post`** for request object, but [**`POST`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) does.

So, use **`request.POST`** instead of **`request.Post`**

```
post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
```

Hence your view be as,

```
def LikePost(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive language. `HttpRequest` does not have `Post` field, it has [`POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) instead. Replace `request.Post.get(...)` with `request.POST.get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use **POST** instead of **Post**. It worked for me